# Creation of Calendar List View doesn't Set Calendar or Default View

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am using the following to create a View in a calendar, but it doesn't create the view as a calendar or set it as the default view. What am I missing?

```
    function createCalendarView() {

        var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostweburl);
        var hostweb = hostcontext.get_web();
        var listCollection = hostweb.get_lists();
        var list = listCollection.getByTitle('Calendar');

        // Create View
        //get the view collection to add the view
        var viewcollection = list.get_views();
        //create a viewinfo with the view properties
        var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
        viewInfo.set_title("MYVIEW"); //set the title
        viewInfo.set_viewTypeKind = 'calendar';
        viewInfo.set_setAsDefaultView = true; //set the view to default
        //add the view to the view collection
        viewcollection.add(viewInfo);
        //load the view collection
        context.load(viewcollection);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onCalendarViewCreationSuccess, onCalendarViewCreationFail);
    }

    function onCalendarViewCreationSuccess() {
        alert('Calendar View created successfully!');
    }

    function onCalendarViewCreationFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to create the Calendar View. ' + args.get_message());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using below changes

```
viewInfo.set_viewTypeKind(524288);
viewInfo.set_setAsDefaultView(true); //set the view to default
```

For a list of `viewTypeKind` refer link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245733.aspx

Also in your code you should change `context.load(viewcollection);` with `hostcontext.load(viewcollection);`

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the Calendar code and have bookmarked this for future reference. I tried using hostcontext, but it would not execute, but context did.

Comment: Ok cool. I didn't see `context` in your code sample.

Comment: My fault for not providing the full sample, as it is a little long.